# Docker / React build for production : my build folder is always empty

Tags: reactjs, docker, api-platform.com

I have a multi staging Dockerfile that works great in development, but when I'm trying to deploy for production the build folder stays empty. I can't see where it goes wrong, should work to me. Here is the Dockerfile :

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=13
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.17


# "development" stage
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_client_common

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

RUN yarn global add @api-platform/client-generator

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
  python \
  make \
  build-base

# prevent the reinstallation of node modules at every changes in the source code
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
  yarn install

COPY . ./

VOLUME /usr/src/client/node_modules

#ENV HTTPS true

FROM api_platform_client_common AS api_platform_client_development

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]


# "build" stage
# depends on the "development" stage above
FROM api_platform_client_common AS api_platform_client_build

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN set -eux; \
  npm run build
  #yarn build

RUN npm install -g serve

CMD serve -s build -l 3000
```

Is part of a more complex docker-compose setup, but I don't think that the rest of files are relevant. When the build steps occurs, I have the logs saying it has been generated :

```
File sizes after gzip:

  914.33 KB  build/static/js/2.fb074eef.chunk.js
  25.57 KB   build/static/js/main.2c9c53c7.chunk.js
  23.82 KB   build/static/css/main.581e45d5.chunk.css
  12.56 KB   build/static/css/2.5dd93f16.chunk.css
  773 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.09b85ec0.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
```

But when I visit the served content by npm serve, I just get "Files within build /" with blank window. When I run "ls /usr/src/client/build" in my docker container, it's in fact empty...

Can someone see what's wrong ?

Thanks !